# Print data from controller to view with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

im new to laravel framework and im try to print the data in view

```
public function show($id) {

    return view('showpost')->with('data',array('data'=>Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail()));
}
```

this function return array of data , how would i print it in view (showpost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$data = array('data' => Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail());`

When it actually should be (I guess) `$data = Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();`

You need to do the following:

```
public function show($id) {

  return view('showpost', array(
          'data'  =>  Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail()
       )
  );
}

// OR

public function show($id) {

  return view('showpost')
         ->with('data', Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail());
}
```

From  [Laravel Doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views) :

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

> When passing information in this manner, $data should be an array with key/value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as . As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the with method to add individual pieces of data to the view:

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```